# Saving date into SQLite Database using javafx wrong

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, datepicker

Whenever I try to enter the date into the database using my JavaFX JFXDatePicker in the application. However, it always enters the date as '1992'. I don't even have 1992 available in the choices.

[image]
[image]

When I print the DatePicker.getValue() the correct date is being printed to the console.
This is the code:

```
public void RemRoom() {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Rooms.db");
        pst = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tp + " set isAvail = 'false' where RoomID = '" + rm + "'");
        pst.execute();
        LocalDate sd = ControllerScr2.getInstance().chkIn.getValue();
        System.out.println(sd); 
        pst = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE " + tp + " set StartDate = " + sd + " where RoomID = '" + rm + "'");
        pst.execute();
        pst.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The fields you use to store dates are `REAL`. This means you do not have to give them a date directly, but first convert it to the correct format.
For this purpose, `SQLite` offers the `julianday` function that accepts as a string argument containing the date and returns a value of type `REAL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried formatting the date picked?

```
myDatePicker.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```

There's also some useful info on how to manipulate DatePickers [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm)